# TupletUp or TupletDown not working for me

Tags: lilypond, tuplet

On version 2.24.1, I'm trying to apply direction to my tuplets with `\tupletUp` and/or `\tupletDown` but it doesn't work. `\tuplet 3/2 {...}` is working fine but when I change it got this message:

```
error: syntax error, unexpected FRACTION
  \tupletUp 
            3/2 {...}
```

Yes, I can use `\override` as shown [here](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/learning/within_002dstaff-objects) but that's not my point

**EDIT:**

This is what I'm trying to achieve. Writing this I've found that `\arpeggio` works but `\arpeggioUp` doesn't. Related?)

[image: Example 1]

Example Code:

```
\version "2.24.1"
\language "espanol"

\relative sol' {
  \key do \minor
  \time 5/4
  <fa' re'>2.  \tuplet 3/1 { re'4 mib8 re do re }
}
```

Output:

[image: Example 1 output]

Using `\tupletUp` (as @jeanas suggests)

```
<fa' re'>2.  \tupletUp { re'4 mib8 re do re }
```

Produces:

[image: Example 2 output]

Comment: Are you still including `\tuplet` in the code, like `\tupletUp \tuplet 3/2 { c''8 d e }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in a comment, `\tupletUp` and `\tupletDown` should be added but not replace `\tuplet`. The error message you get happens because `\tupletUp` stands on its own, and the next thing in your file is `3/2`, which LilyPond doesn’t know how to interpret.

Note that `\tupletUp` will set the direction for *all* subsequent tuplets, but you can use `\once \tupletUp` to restrict it to one tuplet only.

Comment: Yes, now I see what you meant `<fa' re'>2.  \tupletUp \tuplet 3/1 { re'4 mib8 re do re }`